# Create own function that checks for null value and returns an empty string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, function

If I have a class like below, how would I create the function nullToEmptyString()?
If object is DBNull.Value then return an empty string, otherwise return the value. The function should work on every object in person.

```
public class Person
{
    public object surname { get; set; }
    public object lastname { get; set; }
    public object zip_code { get; set; }
    public object tele { get; set; }
}
```

I retrieve a list of persons from the DB and I want to print the value, if it has a value, otherwise an empty string.

```
foreach (var person in listFromDB)
{
    person.surname.nullToEmptyString()
    person.lastname.nullToEmptyString()
}
```

**EDIT**
In short, this function should work like the .ToString() function but would also be able to handle DBNull values.

Comment: A string is immutable, so you cannot change the current instance. You'll have to use a syntax like: person.surname = person.surname.nullToEmptyString();

Comment: So the two answers here are invalid?

Comment: Nopes. They both are valid. it depends whether you wish to modify the person class values or you want to display. If you wish to modify, you need to do as suggested by @Arjen, or else I have just displayed the values which can even be taken in separate variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static string nullToEmptyString(this string dbStr)
{
    return (dbStr == null || dbStr == "") ? "" : dbStr;
}

foreach (var person in listFromDB)
{
    Response.Write(person.surname.nullToEmptyString());
    Response.Write(person.lastname.nullToEmptyString());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ah, so *this* points to the object you run .nullToEmptyString() on?

Comment: Yes. This is a new fundamental kin C# 3.0 called as extension methods.

Comment: Where should I create this function? I get the error `Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class` if I try to make it a function in my Person class.

Comment: Ah yes. Forgot. You can create a new static class and define the above method as static.

Comment: Yep, works like a charm =). I only need it for print and not to actually change the type.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
public string Somename(this string somestring)
{
      return somestring ?? "";
}
```